# why cant I rotate this Text

Tags: modifiers, normals, text-object

I'm trying to rotate this text around a pen to emboss it. but instead of rotating the text horizontally around the pen I am trying to stretch it around the cylinder vertically. I know there's is something I am missing. I have tried using an empty as the ref point but no matter how i play with the xyz rotation and location the text always seems to rotate from the ends instead of down the middle like I want. I have tried using text  concerted to a  mesh as well as svg file i made and nothing seems to work. I know its something simple.. but after spending an evening or two word bending I've decided to call in the big guns!. [image: the red is kind of what i want the text to do]
[image: here is what I'm getting... basically doing the matrix..]
[image: This is what I want to do .. but ... vertically.. I mean seems like it should work.. but it just keeps ending up with a twist.]

Comment: i can feel the pain - i struggled with that a lot in the beginning too. It is everything else than intuitive, i hope my answer helps.

Comment: To add to Chris' answer, make sure that you've applied the rotation in Object mode (Ctrl A)

Comment: IT WORKED!  I swear I tried this like 30 times already. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

1. add a text, extrude -> R Y 90

[image]

2. add remesh modifier, sharp, uncheck remove disconnected, octree depth 9

[image]

3. add an empty -> R Z 90

[image]

4. add simple deform modifier, bend, z,  100 degrees (or whatever you like), object: empty

[image]

It might not be the fastest way, but it works.

Comment: In most cases (in my opinion or common usages), add an empty, rotate its Y up to Z axis (or down to -Z) and bend either on X or Z the deformed object.

Comment: nice hint! didn't know that!